# How to refactor this code using DRY principals?

Tags: c#, generics, dry

I have two functions that I want to combine using generics.

```
    static public DataTable GetDataTable(SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql,
        string connectionString, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

        foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in parameters)
        { da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter); }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    static public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql,
        string connectionString, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

        foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in parameters)
        { da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter); }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

This is what I came up with:

```
    static private T GetDataX<T>(T container
        , SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql, string connectionString
        , CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ) where T : System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent, new()
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

        foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in parameters)
        { da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter); }

        da.Fill(container); // ERROR: cannot convert from 'T' to 'System.Data.DataTable'
        return container;
    }
```

But I get the error shown above.

If I change container to dynamic it compiles.  But that seems like a hack.
What is the proper way to combine the two functions?

Comment: Mandatory comment: Close your connections. Or better: don't even open them, let `da.Fill()` manage it.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I've edited my code above to have da.Fill() manage the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `Action` parameter to do the fill for each type you want to support:

```
static private T GetDataX<T>(SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql, string connectionString, Action<T, SqlDataAdapter> fillAction, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure) 
    where T : System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent, new()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in parameters)
    { da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter); }

    T container = new T();
    fillAction(container, da);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    return container;
}
```

Then you can write your other methods in terms of this one:

```
static public DataTable GetDataTable(SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql,
        string connectionString, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    return GetDataX<DataTable>(parameters, sql, connectionString, (dt, adapter) => { adapter.Fill(dt); }, commandType);
}

static public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql,
        string connectionString, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    return GetDataX<DataSet>(parameters, sql, connectionString, (ds, adapter) => { adapter.Fill(ds); }, commandType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `DataSet` and `DataTable` are entirely separate classes, and you have to use a different overload of `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` for each of them, you're not going to be able to use a generic method to simplify your two methods down into one. However, you can reduce the repeating code using a method that takes a delegate that defines what to do with the `SqlDataAdapter` during the course of the method.

```
public static DataTable GetDataSet(
    SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql, string connectionString,
    CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    UseDataAdapter(
       parameters, sql, connectionString,
       da => da.Fill(ds), commandType
    );
    return ds;
}

public static DataTable GetDataTable(
    SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql, string connectionString,
    CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    UseDataAdapter(
       parameters, sql, connectionString,
       da => da.Fill(dt), commandType
    );
    return dt;
}

public static void UseDataAdapter(
    SqlParameterHash parameters, string sql, string connectionString,
    Action<SqlDataAdapter> adapterAction,
    CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    foreach (SqlParameter Parameter in parameters)
    { da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter); }

    adapterAction(da);

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Typically I would agree with you, but the overhead of using `dynamic` has the potential of slowing down your code by orders of magnitude. I think using `dynamic` is akin to taking a sledgehammer to a nail.